# Microsoft HPC Jobs Dependency

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc

I'm using Microsoft HPC 2008 R2 Cluster Manager and I need to add dependency between several jobs but I found out that Microsft has not this feature in the HPC system (however we can add dependedency between tasks ) 
I searched but I found a trial solution : http://totalcae.com/blog/2011/08/job-dependencies-in-hpc-server-2008-r2/ 
is there any other solution for this need

Answer (score 0):

this feature is available in HPC Pack 2012
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919649.aspx#BKMK_JobProperties